# How to make a spinner pop up in middle of screen instead of drop down?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

I would like that when uses touches on a spinner, instead of having items drop down below the spinner, the items where in the center of screen with title, like it was in older versions of Android, just like this:

[image]

I use API 19. What should I do?

Later I will have to implement multi-selection and I think this way UX is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy and simple: create a Dialog with a RadioGroup.

You dont even need a Spinner, you just need a View with an OnItemClickListener:

> ```
>  spinner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v){
>           Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
>           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
>
>           RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_radiogroup);
>           for(int i=0; i<radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i){
>               RadioButton radio  = (RadioButton) ((ViewGroup) radioGroup).getChildAt(i);
>               if(radio.isChecked()) {
>                      // do something with the selection
>               }
>           }
>           dialog.show();
>       }
>  });
> ```